# jhipster app : gulp error while packaging

Tags: node.js, gulp, jhipster

I have an old jhipster v3 application installed on a new computer (ubuntu 16.04).

```
node -v
v8.12.0
npm -v
6.4.1
```

When I try to package it :

```
mvn -Pprod package -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I am getting this error

```
[10:01:26] 'ngconstant:dev' errored after 28 ms
[10:01:26] Error in plugin 'gulp-tslint-log'
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received null
```

Any idea about where this issue could come from?

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
        <fileset>
            <directory>target/www/</directory>
        </fileset>
        <fileset>
            <directory>node_modules</directory>
        </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Looks like a wrong version of nodejs (too recent) but it's surprising because for a prod build, the version of node is forced in pom.xml. Have you changed it?

Comment: the only reference to node in pom.xml is in maven-clean-plugin (see my update)

Comment: Sorry, this is probably because JHipster 3 did not have this way of doing. Anyway, try downgrading node to 6.x

Comment: 6.x doesn't fix it. It works on a ubuntu 14.04 with node 4.8.7. Does that mean I should downgrade the pc to that level?

Comment: Yes, you should use nvm to quickly switch between several versions of node depending on the project you work on.